# Grid.SelectedRow.Cells.Item(1).Text.ToString returns unencoded characters like Bol& #237;vares

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, encoding

I am filling a form with the data from the selected row of a gridview in asp.net

```
TXTName.Text = Grid.SelectedRow.Cells.Item(1).Text.ToString
```

Returns : Bol& #237;vares Fuertes

```
TXTName.Text = Grid.DataKeys(grdMaestro.SelectedRow.RowIndex).Values(1).ToString
```

Returns: "Bolívares Fuertes"

with the first way the letters with accents show up like &#XXX  with the second it works fine. the problem with the second way is that i have to include all the rows in the [datakeynames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames.aspx) attribute, and it could cause some problems if i end up using the automatic update and delete features of the gridview controller.

NOTE: I inserted a space between "Bol&" **AND** "#237;vares Fuertes" because stackoverflow fixed it in the preview

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Substitute this

```
TXTName.Text = Grid.SelectedRow.Cells.Item(1).Text.ToString
```

with

```
TXTName.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Grid.SelectedRow.Cells.Item(1).Text.ToString)
```

And see if it works now.

Good luck

Comment: You beat me by 2 mins ;o) I need to type faster!

Comment: @bUKaneer hehehe, :P sorry!